# Thoughts on doing MySQL queries vs using SESSION variables?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Just curious how other people feel about this.  Will appreciate opinions or facts, whatever you got :)

I am working on an application where a lot of info is pulled from MySQL and needed on multiple pages.

Would it make more sense to...

1. Pull all data ONCE and store it in SESSION variables to use on other pages
2. Pull the data from the database on each new page that needs it

I assume the preferred method is #1, but maybe there is some downside to using SESSION variables "too much"?

Side question that's kind of related:  As far as URLs, is it preferable to have data stored in them (i.e. domain.com/somepage.php?somedata=something&otherdata=thisdata) or use SESSION variables to store that data so the URLs can stay general/clean (i.e. domain.com/somepage.php)?

Both are probably loaded questions but any possible insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Another good resource: http://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/

Comment: This will also largely depend on the supporting architecture. For example, at one place I have worked with used Oracle with a very small amount of RAM on the servers, and at another we used MySQL with a large amount of RAM. In the first case we let the queries do the bulk of the work because Oracle could handle it, at the second we used (abused) Sessions because we had the memory resources to do so.

Comment: It depends on several factors but as a rule of thumb using session storage is faster than querying MySQL in most scenarios.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time - "side questions" make it hard to answer. Also, try to ask specific questions, not "appreciate opinions".

Answer (score 4):

Your question can't be answered to the point where the answer is applicable everywhere.

Here's why: many web server architectures deal with having HTTP server (Apache, Nginx), serverside language (PHP, Ruby, Python) and RDBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL) on one and the same machine.

That's one of the most common setups you can find.

Now, this is what happens in your scenario:

- You connect to MySQL - you establish a connection from PHP > MySQL and that "costs" a little
- You request the data, so MySQL reads it from the hard drive (unless cached in RAM)
- PHP gets the data and allocates some memory to hold the information
- Now you save that to a session. But by default, sessions are disk based so you just issued a write operation and you spent at least 1 I/O operation of your hard drive

But let's look at what happened - you moved some data from disk (MySQL) to RAM (PHP variable) which then gets saved at disk again.

You really didn't help yourself or your system in that case, what happens is that you made things slower.

On the other hand, PHP (and other languages) are capable of maintaining connections to MySQL (and other databases) so they minimize the cost of opening a new connection (which is really inexpensive in the grand scheme of things).

As you can see, this is one scenario. There's a scenario where you have your HTTP server on a dedicated machine, PHP on dedicated machine and MySQL on dedicated machine. The question is, again, is it cheaper to move data from MySQL to a PHP session. Is that session disk based, redis based, memcache based, database based? What's the cost of establishing the connection to MySQL?

What you need to ask, in any scenario that you can imagine - **what are you trading off and for what**?

So, if you are running the most common setup (PHP and your database on the same machine) - the answer is NO, it's not better to store some MySQL data in a session.
If you use InnoDB (and you probably are) and if it's optimized properly, saving some data to a session to avoid apparent overhead of querying the db for **reads** won't yield benefits. It's most likely going to be quite the opposite.

Comment: I upvoted this as the comment "Not Applicable Everywhere" is a good caveat, but I feel the question in general should be closed as opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it into the session is almost always a **terrible** idea. It's not even worth considering unless you've exhausted all other options.

Here's how you tackle these problems:

- Evaluate if there's anything you can do to simplify the query you're running, like trim down on the columns you fetch. Instead of `SELECT *` try `SELECT x,y` where those are the only columns you need.
- Use `EXPLAIN` to find out why the query is taking so long. Look for any easy wins like **adding indexes**.
- Check that your MySQL server is properly tuned. The default configuration is terrible and some simple one-line fixes can boost performance dramatically.
- If, and only if, you've tried all these things and you can't squeeze out any more performance, you want to try and cache the results.

You only pull the pin on caching because caching is one of the hardest things to get right.

You can use something like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) act as a faster store for pre-refetched results. They're designed to automatically expire cached data that's no longer used.

The reason using `$_SESSION` is a bad idea is because once data is put in there very few take the time to properly expunge it later, leading to an ever growing session. If you're concerned about performance, keep your sessions as small as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Just think about your users(client pc). session takes some spaces to user pc, also session can get lost, may e after closing page, or copying the link and paste it to other browser. God practice there i think just use query, but note something, try as much as possible to reduce number of queries in page, it will slow down your site.